# Match a String in a Webpage along with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

With below code, I am trying to match a text in a web page to get rid of html tags in a page.

```
   var body = $(body);
   var str = "Search me in a Web page";
   body.find('*').filter(function()
   {
     $(this).text().indexOf(str) > -1;
   }).addClass('FoundIn');
   $('.FoundIn').text() = $('.FoundIn').text().replace(str,"<span class='redT'>"+str+"</span>");
```

But it does not seems to work.. Please have a look at this and let me know where the problem is...
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4vXx/) is the fiddle 
I have tried the below code instead..

```
function searchText() 
 {
  var rep = body.text();
  alert(rep);
  var temp = "<font style='color:blue; background-color:yellow;'>";
  temp = temp + str;
  temp = temp + "</font>";
  var rep1 = rep.replace(str,temp);
  body.html(rep1);
 }
```

But that is totally removing html tags from body...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change last line of your code to below one...**you are using assignment operator which works with variables not with jquery object** ..So you need to pass the replaced html to text method.

```
$('.FoundIn').text($('.FoundIn').text().replace(str,"<span class='redT'>"+str+"</span>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this.
$('*:contains("Search me in a Web page")').text("<span class='redT'>Search me in a Web page</span>");
```